# C++ - Runtime error on string input inside loop

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error

I have observed a pattern of error in some of my previous programs, which I am not able to understand that why the pattern is repeating?

For example, in the below program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct tree
{
    string b;
    int val;
    tree *left,*right;
};

int main()
{
    tree *start,*temp,*tem;
    string a;                               //Declaring string a here
    int t,n,k,m;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n>>k>>m;
        cin>>a;                            //Input to a for first time,working
        start=new tree;
        start->b=a;
        start->val=1;
        n--;
        while(n--)
        {
            temp=start;
            cin>>a;                         //Input to a, working only once
            while(1)
            {
                if(a.substr(0,m)<=temp->b.substr(0,m))
                {
                    temp->val++;
                    if(temp->left)
                    temp=temp->left;
                    else
                    {
                        tem=new tree;
                        tem->b=a;
                        tem->val=1;
                        temp->left=tem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(temp->right)
                    temp=temp->right;
                    else
                    {
                        tem=new tree;
                        tem->b=a;
                        tem->val=1;
                        temp->right=tem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            temp=start;
            while(1)
            {
                if(temp->val==k)
                {
                    cout<<temp->b<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                else if(temp->val<k)
                {
                    k--;
                    temp=temp->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    k=k-temp->val;
                    temp=temp->right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have declared string a inside my main(). When I am storing input in string 'a' for first time, its working.

After that I have used it inside a loop. In the loop it takes input only once & then gives runtime error: Segmentation fault(Core Dumped)

After many tests, I found that it is giving runtime error just after taking input for first time inside loop. I have experienced this same situation in two other problems.
In one of the problems that I was able to solve, I observed that the error stopped showing after modifications in an integer value which was not at all related to string, it was just in the same loop as the string. I checked the value of every data inside the loop but didn't find any connection between them.

The format of the loops and placement of string was same in the other problems as in this.

Why is this giving error after first input inside the loop?

If anyone requires, the link of the problem statement is: https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/xenny-and-partially-sorted-strings-7/

I should not have initialized the left & right pointers in that way, but doing that in the proper way is also not solving the issues.

I have checked the value of every variable just before the faulty cin statement & value of every variable is proper until that point.

Comment: Start the practice of using proper variable names in your codes before it's too late

Comment: cant you reduce the code? What is all this other stuff good for when your question is about reading a string?

Comment: You never initialize `start->left` and `start->right`.

Comment: @FirstStep Its for practice & the variable names that I have used are given as it is in the problem statement

Comment: @tobi303 Reading string is just a part of program, I posted the entire code, in case I am making mistake at some other place which I am not able to notice

Comment: This reads like C code, I would encourage you to learn about constructors.

Comment: @Barmar Actually I didn't initialize in first attempt but after lots of attempt I went experimenting with other parts of program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create new trees, you don't initialize `left` and `right`. Your code assumes that they're automatically initialized to `nullptr`, but you need to do that explicitly. As a result, when you do `if (temp->left)` and `if (temp->right)`, you're testing uninitialized values, which results in undefined behavior.

Another problem is that you have the loop that searches for the `k`th string inside the input loop. It should be after it. And it needs to check for a null pointer before dereferencing `temp`.

Other things you should fix: use `getline` rather than `>>` to read the inputs, since the problem statement says that it's one string per line. `cin >> a;` will just read a single word, not a whole line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct tree {
    string b;
    int val;
    tree *left,*right;
};

int main() {
    tree *start,*temp,*tem;
    string a;                               //Declaring string a here
    int t,n,k,m;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        cin>>n>>k>>m;
        cin>>a;                            //Input to a for first time,working
        start=new tree;
        start->b=a;
        start->val=1;
        start->left = start->right = nullptr;
        n--;
        while(n--) {
            temp=start;
            cin>>a;                         //Input to a, working only once
            while(1) {
                if(a.substr(0,m)<=temp->b.substr(0,m)) {
                    temp->val++;
                    if(temp->left)
                        temp=temp->left;
                    else {
                        tem=new tree;
                        tem->b=a;
                        tem->val=1;
                        tem->left = tem->right = nullptr;
                        temp->left=tem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(temp->right)
                        temp=temp->right;
                    else {
                        tem=new tree;
                        tem->b=a;
                        tem->val=1;
                        tem->left = tem->right = nullptr;
                        temp->right=tem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        temp=start;
        while(temp) {
            if(temp->val==k) {
                cout<<temp->b<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp->val<k) {
                k--;
                temp=temp->left;
            }
            else {
                k=k-temp->val;
                temp=temp->right;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes, but its still giving runtime error at the same place that I have mentioned in my question

Comment: OK, time for you to start using a debugger to step through the program and check the variables.

Comment: Checked the value of every variable, everything is alright just before "cin>>a" (Second cin>>a, not first one) . As soon as it inputs string a, RUNTIME ERROR

Comment: Is this the whole program? You could have a problem in some other part of the program and it's corrupting memory.

Comment: This is the whole program, the link to the problem statement is also given in the question. I have checked value of every variable just before cin.

Comment: You are right, the problem is because of that part, on commenting out that part the program runs beyond the cin statement

Comment: why do you have the second loop inside the first loop? Shouldn't it be after you've entered all the strings?

Comment: Got my mistake, that loop should be outside the inner loop which by mistaken i placed inside the inner loop